# How long do moderators serve?

Tags: discussion, moderator-elections

Will we be holding periodic elections, and if so, is this to add more moderators or reelect the existing moderators?  In a broader sense, I'd be interested in hearing the level of commitment needed for this position.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If elected you moderate for as long as you want to, you won't have to stand for re-election (at least that's the way it is at the moment).

As a site grows more moderators may be added - either from the runners-up in the previous election or via a new election. Also if any moderators stand down an election may be held to find a replacement.

You're volunteering so how long you serve is up to you.

Comment: Additionally, because the current moderators were appointed [pro tem](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) instead of elected, they will need to nominate themselves in the election if they wish to continue as a moderator.  All permanent moderators should be elected by the community.

Comment: @Rebecca: in that case, I'm really hoping it's standard practice for people with experience to wait 'til the last second to submit their own nomination.

Comment: @B Mitch - Don't forget there are three phases. Nomination, primary where there's public voting and election where there's a secret ballot. Depending on the number of candidates one or more step may be omitted.

Answer (score 6):

See discussion at

[Should Community Moderators be "elected for life", or have terms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/should-community-moderators-be-elected-for-life-or-have-terms)

Consensus was:

> Yeah, It should be 'for life'.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  I knew it had to have been answered somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Speaking from experience, it's not a huge commitment.  This site is still fairly small and there are very few issues that come up that really require moderator attention.

With three moderators, I wouldn't expect this to take more than 5-10 minutes a day (tops) to pop in and review/resolve any outstanding issues.